# How to set JMSType as a subscriber in Java?

Tags: java, push-notification, activemq-classic

Here's how I'm subscribing to a message queue over OpenWire protocol:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.jms.*;


//..........
subscriberPublishSubscribe = new Subscriber();
subscriberPublishSubscribe.create(URL, "login", "pass", TOPICNAME, SUBSCRIPTIONID);

//.......
Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
connection.setClientID(clientId);
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic topic = session.createTopic(topicName);
messageConsumer = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, subId);
JMSMessageListener listener = new JMSMessageListener();
messageConsumer.setMessageListener(listener);
connection.start();
```

How can I filter messages using the class `JMSType`? Here's a code I'll probably need to use:

```
Message msg = session.createMessage();
msg.setJMSType("some_jms_type");

// What's next?
```

Once again, I'm a **subscriber**, not a producer, therefore I want to **receive** only messages with a certain `JMSType`.

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly unclear from your problem statement but it sounds like you want to filter messages based on their set JMSType which is done using a [JMS selector](http://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html) expression passed into the createConsumer method.

You create selector expression to filter what you want such as:

```
JMSType = 'car' AND color = 'blue' AND weight > 2500
```

But keep in mind that a message broker is not a database and treating it as such usually ends in tears.

A quick Google of 'JMS Message selectors' will give you a wealth of reading on the subject.

Comment: I know what it is and how to create it. I'm asking how to use it in my case.

Comment: Then you need to ask it in a way that people know what you are asking, I've got no clue what more you want to know.